# I would like to show the messages on the page of group pages..but

Tags: ruby-on-rails

**1.I would like to show the messages, which come from the members who already have joined the group, on the group page.**

**2.Then, I wrote the code as below,**

**(show.html.erb-group)**

```
    <% @group_messages.each do |gm| %>
      <div class="message_area">
      <p class= "member_name"><a href="/members/<%= gm.member_id %>">
       <%= gm.member_id %></a></p>
      <p class="message_content"><%= gm.content %></p>
      <p class="message_create">(<%= gm.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
      </p></div>
      </tr>
    <% end %>
```

**(groups_controller)**

```
def show
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])

    if !checklogin? then return end
    groupfriends = GroupInMember.where(:member_id => session[:login].id)
    gflist = '('
    groupfriends.each do |gf|
      gflist += gf.member_id.to_s + ","
    end
    gflist += session[:login].id.to_s + ')'
    @query = "select * from group_in_members where member_id in " +  gflist 
    @group_messages = GroupMessage.find_by_sql(@query)

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # index.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @group_messages }
    end



    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # show.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @group }
    end
  end
```

3.Then, I got an error message like so

```
missing attribute: content
Extracted source (around line #23):

20:   <div class="message_area">
21:   <p class= "member_name"><a href="/members/<%= gm.member_id %>">
22:    <%= gm.member_id %></a></p>
23:   <p class="message_content"><%= gm.content %></p>
24:   <p class="message_create">(<%= gm.created_at.strftime'%Y-%m-%d %H:%M' %>)
25:   </p></div>
26:   </tr>
```

4.How can I solve this? Could you give me a hint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting columns from 'group_in_members' table when finding messages.

Answer (score 0):

The `missing attribute` error means you performed a query that did not include an attribute that is being called in your view.

You're using `select * from group_in_members` in a query that is being run on the `GroupMessage` class. It seems to me you should be using `select * from group_messages` instead.

Or, if you wanna go the ActiveRecord way and make it a lot cleaner in the process,

```
gflist = groupfriends.pluck(:member_id)
gflist << session[:login].id
@group_messages = GroupMessage.where(:member_id => gflist)
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. I changed "group_in_members" to "group_messages" and then could solve the problem. Thank you very much.